# Serialize Ruby Hash in Batches

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9.3

I need to serialize a large hash into the form `key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3...`. I need to do it for every 100 keys, and send the string to a remote server.

```
def batch_serialize(h, size)
  h_as_a = h.to_a
  while h_as_a.length > 0 do
    batch = Hash[h_as_a.slice!(0,size)]
    serialized = []
    batch.each_pair { |k,v| serialized += "#{k}=#{v}" }
    transmit(serialized.join(', '))
  end
end
```

There should be an easier way to get chunks of an Hash (or to split the hash into multiple, smaller hashes) and operate on them.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), doing as below

```
def batch_serialize(h, size)
  h.each_slice(size) do |rows|
    serialized = rows.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}" }
    transmit(serialized.join(', '))
  end
end
```

Comment: I think [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!